# White grid appears when reprojecting DEM in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, dem, arcgis-10.5

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.5.

I have a DEM .tif archive, in WGS 84. The specifics are:[image]

[image]

Then, I try to reproject it to WGS 84 UTM 19S.
Project and transformations -> Raster-> Project Raster
I use the original as the input, and in output coordinate system I choose WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_19S. However, when the process is finished, I get

[image]

Why does this happen, and how do I solve it?

Comment: Try to use `Billinear` as interpolation method. [Esri help](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/project-raster.htm)

Comment: @MrXsquared I tried bilinear, cubic and majority, but I get the same result.